# Django url regex question

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I have the following url

```
url(r'^(?P<name>[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$', 'user', name='user')
```

This matches URLS like `/tom/` and `/tom-max/` but not on URL's like `/tom-2/` or `tom-brandy-monster` which I want.

Basically I would like to capture a combination of hyphens, letters and numbers.

**UPDATE**

This is in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'homepage.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^user/', include('users.urls')),
    url(r'^plans/', include('plans.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

This is in my users/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'users.views',
    url(r'^(?P<user>[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$', 'user', name='user'), 
)
```

**UPDATE2**

The fault was in my views. This regex works for all the above-mentioned examples.

Comment: That looks like it should work. I suggest looking closely at patterns that occur before this one to see if they are snagging the request before it gets to this pattern.

Comment: @Peter: you are correct; see my answer.

Comment: That is `users.urls.py`? I hope you mean `users/urls.py`?

Comment: I'm not sure quite what's wrong. I presume in your testing you are prefixing them all with `user/`. And I presume that the only thing that you've left out of your `urls.py` files as they are put here are the imports?

Comment: Why do you believe that it doesn't match those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there *will* match all of these that you have specified (see below). You should check to make sure that (a) you don't have a URL pattern which will match earlier and (b) that this one is being included (one common culprit is using `urlpatterns = ...` rather than `urlpatterns += ...` after initialising it).

```
>>> import re
>>> urlpattern = re.compile(r'^(?P<name>[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$')
>>> urlpattern.match('tom/').group('name')
'tom'
>>> urlpattern.match('tom-max/').group('name')
'tom-max'
>>> urlpattern.match('tom-2/').group('name')
'tom-2'
>>> urlpattern.match('tom-brandy-monster/').group('name')
'tom-brandy-monster'
```

Comment: Hi Chris Morgan, could yo have a look at my URLS to see what could be wrong? Thanks!